# System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException in my Authentication controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework

New with c# and entity framework.
My controller LogIn doesn't work when accessing the dbcontext to compare the login user as entered in the form.

The problem is with this line on the controller :

```
var personne = db.Personnes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LoginPersonne == login);
```

Here's the class:

```
[Table("PERSONNE")]
public class Personne
{
    // Propriétés de la classe User
    [Key]
    [Column("ID_PERSONNE")]
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IdPersonne { get; set; }
    //[Required]
    [Column("NOM_PERSONNE")]
    public string NomPersonne { get; set; }
    [Column("PRENOM_PERSONNE")]
    public string PrenomPersonne { get; set; }
    [Column("LOGIN_PERSONNE")]
    [Display(Name = "Nom d’utilisateur: ")]
    public string LoginPersonne { get; set; }
    #region Properties link
    // Lien Many to Many avec Evenement (Une personne peut s'inscrire à plusieurs Evenements)
    [Column("ID_EVENEMENT")]
    [ForeignKey("IdEvenement")]
    public virtual ICollection<Evenement> Evenements { get; set; }
    // Lien One to Many avec Statut (Une personne a 1 et 1 seul statut)
    [Column("ID_STATUT_PERSONNE")]
    public int IdStatutPersonne { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdStatutPersonne")]
    public virtual StatutPersonne statutsPersonne { get; set; }
}
```

controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(Models.Personne personne)
    {
        // On regarde si le modèle est valide
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(IsValid(personne.LoginPersonne))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(personne.LoginPersonne, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login n'existe pas");
            }
        }
        return View(personne);
    }

    // Méthode pour vérifier si le login est dans la base
    private bool IsValid(string login)
    {
        bool isValid = false;

        using (var db = new AgendaContext())
        {
            var personne = db.Personnes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LoginPersonne == login);

            if (personne != null)
            {
                if (personne.LoginPersonne == login)
                {
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

Thanks a lot! (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

Forgot the dbcontext :

> ```
>     public AgendaContext() : base("OracleDbContext")
>     {
>     }
>     #endregion
>     #region Properties
>     public DbSet<Personne> Personnes { get; set; }
>     public DbSet<StatutPersonne> StatutsPersonne { get; set; }
>     public DbSet<Evenement> Evenements { get; set; }
>     public DbSet<Lieu> Lieux { get; set; }
>     public DbSet<CategorieEvenement> CategoriesEvenement { get; set; }
>     #endregion
>     #region Methods
>     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
>     {
>         modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("AGENDACTCS");
>         modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
>         modelBuilder.Entity<Personne>().
>             HasMany(t => t.Evenements).
>             WithMany(t => t.Personnes).
>             Map(
>             m =>
>             {
>                 m.MapLeftKey("ID_PERSONNE");
>                 m.MapRightKey("ID_EVENEMENT");
>                 m.ToTable("RESERVATION");
>             });
> ```

```
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);  
    }
```

Comment: var personne = db.Personnes.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LoginPersonne == login); surely you want var personne = db.Personnes(p => p.LoginPersonne == login).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: doesn't work with FirstOrDefault at the end...Can't run the solution